# Hosting and closing a single-use connection via ASP.NET WebService

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services

We have a supplier service which we access via a TCP/IP connection, but we can only ever have a single login active at any time. As this service is accessed from several apps we set up a WebService (ASMX) and added a `Mutex` to control access so only one call is made at a time.

However, the service has to connect, log in, issue a command and then logout each time in the current code (below).

```
  using (var client = new Client(connectionSettings))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            client.Login();
                            response.Response = client.SendCommand(command);
                            response.ErrorCode = WebserviceErrorCode.Success;
                            _lastSuccessfulConnection = DateTime.Now;
                        }
                        catch (IOException oex)
                        {
                            response.ErrorMessage = oex.Message;
                            response.ErrorCode = WebserviceErrorCode.UnabletoConnect;
                            return response;
                        }
                        catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException socEx)
                        {
                            response.ErrorMessage = socEx.Message;
                            response.ErrorCode = WebserviceErrorCode.SocketException;
                            return response;
                        }

                        client.Logout();
                    }
```

This is obviously inefficient if several clients are making requests - we would rather hold the connection open for, say 10 seconds and then close it if no further commands come in.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this safely on ASP.NET. Should we use Hangfire, QueueBackgroundWorkItem ?

Comment: what's the reason you can't simply ask for more connections to suit your needs?

Comment: The service is controlled by an external supplier and we can only use a single connection at any time. Hence we have to push all our requests through this narrow singleton webservice.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question...I asked why you can't request more connections from the supplier. Surely if you pay more or something they'll open it up. That's got to be better than choking your own applications and degrading your service? Or are you operating in some kind of very limited bandwidth scenario or something?

Comment: @ADyson please be assured the I know for a fact supplier cannot support more than one connection. It runs on a VAX system (hosted emulation now I think) dating from the 1990s and they no longer develop new functionality for it.

Comment: No problem...just wanted to be sure...sometimes I find that people haven't considered the obvious solution before setting off to develop a complicated workaround. You'd be surprised... :-)

Comment: Indeed - it would be simpler and remove a performance bottleneck if I could support multiple connections. Alas I must deal with the beast that is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I decided to use [`QueueBackgroundWorkItem`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-background-processes-in-asp-net/)

This schedules a background task that is independent of the request thread, and will therefore keep running after the request completes.

**Note:** This isn't a persistent queuing system (it won't store these if the web process is restarted, for example), but since this is to just close down a connection this is fine for this scenario.

#### Implementation

When a request is made to my service, it uses a `static` class to obtain the single client (access is controlled using a `Mutex`) and issue a command. It then calls this routine:

```
private static void CreateTimeoutCheck()
{
      Action<CancellationToken> workItem = TimeoutConnection;
      System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(workItem);
      Log.Information("A timeout check has been created");
}
```

This will invoke this method in the background:

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Job that runs in background, waits 10 seconds then attempts to close the client
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
 private static async void TimeoutConnection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
     Log.Information("Timeout check waiting...");
     await Task.Delay(timeoutMS);
     Log.Information("Timeout check being made");
     CheckForTimeout();
 }
```

The one thing that makes me uneasy about this approach is that I'm spawning one workitem in the threadpool per request and if the service is used heavily this might cause an issue. However, each one is just doing an async wait, so I am hoping this is not going to cause an issue. The service is used internally so we control the number/frequency of requests to it - I'd be more worried if this was exposed externally.

The `CheckForTimeout` method is pretty simple:

```
/// <summary>
/// Check to see if we have had more recent commands
/// </summary>
private static void CheckForTimeout()
{
    var secsSinceLastCmd = DateTime.Now.Subtract(_lastCommand).TotalSeconds;
    if (secsSinceLastCmd >= clientTimeoutSecs)
    {
        // logout and close client
        Log.Information($"Client timeout: {secsSinceLastCmd:0.0} sec since last command");
        CloseClient();
    }
}
```

I'm going to monitor the updated service for a while to ensure it works okay, but tests so far suggest it's working as expected.